# Icon change in activity state in Gojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, gojs

In Gojs My workflow in activity hoe to change icons.Attach my flow image give me suggestions
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By "icon" are you referring to the gear-shaped figure at the top-left corner of the green nodes?  If so, that is probably implemented either by a **Shape** or by a **Picture**.

If it's a Shape, you either need to change its **Shape.figure** or **Shape.geometry**.

If it's a Picture, you need to change its **Picture.source**.

Either way, remember to make changes within a transaction.